# bs4 find_all возвращает пустой список

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

[Страница](https://www.nike.com/ru/launch/t/womens-react-vision-gravity-purple-volt/)

```
foo = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "available-date-component ncss-brand pb6-sm u-uppercase fs14-sm fs16-md"})
print(foo)
```

Возвращает `[]`

Ожидаю `[<div class="available-date-component ncss-brand pb6-sm u-uppercase fs14-sm fs16-md">Доступно 06.02 в 14:00</div>]`

Почему не находит тег с нужным классом?

Comment: Не удивительно, ведь в исходном коде страницы нет элементов с классом available-date-component.

Comment: "ДОСТУПНО 06.02 В 14:00" - inspect code, это класс этого дива

Comment: Вы уверены, что тот div при загрузке страницы уже был в ней? Мб он был создан из javascript

Comment: Никогда не слышали про фронтенд и ajax? Нажмите Ctrl+U, а в открывшемся окне Ctrl+F и поищите этот класс.

Comment: не работал с аяксом никогда, но я ваш намек понял, благодарю